# What is the difference between 1/4" birch ply handy panel and 1/4" G1S plywood?

Tags: wood

Seen at home depot.  They look exactly the same to my eyes but they are labelled different and at slightly different price points, so I assume there must be a difference.  What might it be?

Handy panel:
[image]
[image]

G1S plywood:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Well to start with do bear in mind this is *Home Depot* birch ply, which would almost certainly be nowhere near the top tier of what birch ply can be (across all sources "birch plywood" is by no means a single entity). So, what's the difference? I presume you looked up G1S online and the definition told you probably the key diff for a lot of applications. Did you slide out one of each and feel the weights? And the 1S refers to one side, so the difference in the appearance one face to the other could be the other major difference.

Comment: BTW I have no clue why these should be so close in price, much less that the birch is cheaper!!

Comment: Looking at the pictures, the "handy panel" looks to have a pretty nice surface while the other is showing the "bad" side (placement of sticker)...The "handy panel" might be the deal. Another Home Depot Anomaly.

Comment: @gnicko, I'd say so in a choice between just these two! Not just going by appearance, but what the core plies are/should be, I think it becomes a no-brainer.... assuming both are actually what the labels say they are. But perhaps only if buying at HD is the only option available, and depending on what the OP wants to do with it.

Comment: Evil Orange has plenty of pricing anomalies. Outside of that, things could simply be in the wrong bin: match the upc on the object to the sticker on the rack before you do a victory dance.